# GAZEBO plugin subscribe to ROS topic

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Greetings, I have some problems making a GAZEBO plugin and a ROS node communicate. The ROS node pubblishes correctly the message on the topic, but the plugin isn't able to acces them.

This is the code of the plugin:

```
// Initialize node
node = transport::NodePtr(new transport::Node());

// Subscribe to the control node
node->Init("gazebo/quetzalcoatl");
std::cout << "Subscribing to " << "~/quetzalcoatl/cmdVelocity" << " topic" << std::endl;
commandSubscriber = node->Subscribe("~/quetzalcoatl/cmdVelocity", &SkidSteer::updateVelocity, this);
std::cout << "Subscribed to " << commandSubscriber << std::endl;

// Listen to the update event, this event is broadcast every simulation iteration
this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(
boost::bind(&SkidSteer::OnUpdate, this, _1));
```

This is the code of the ROS node which pubblishes the message:

```
while (ros::ok())
{
    ROS_INFO("Node '%s' sending the %d message", ros::this_node::getName().c_str(), count);

    // Update the velocities
    linearVelocity = 10 + count / 100;
    angularVelocity = 0;

    // Fill the message
    cmdVelocityMsg.linearVelocity = linearVelocity;
    cmdVelocityMsg.angularVelocity = angularVelocity;
    cmdVelocityMsg.moveUp = moveUp;
    cmdVelocityMsg.moveDown = moveDown;
    cmdVelocityMsg.moveLeft = moveLeft;
    cmdVelocityMsg.moveRigth = moveRigth;

    cmdVelocityPub.publish(cmdVelocityMsg);

    ros::spinOnce();
    // Sleep untill next loop, Gazebo must be running or it won't work
    loopRate.sleep();

    // ROS_INFO("Sleeped");

    ++count;
}
```

This is the message used by the plugin:

```
package quetzalcoatlMsgs.msgs;

message cmdVelocity
{
    required float linearVelocity = 1;
    required float angularVelocity = 2;
    required bool moveUp = 3;
    required bool moveDown = 4;
    required bool moveLeft = 5;
    required bool moveRigth = 6;
}
```

This is the message used by the node:

```
float32 linearVelocity
float32 angularVelocity
bool moveUp
bool moveDown
bool moveLeft
bool moveRigth
```

What I'm doing wrong? Also it is correct to declare two different messages, one for the node and one for the plugin, which refer to the same topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14062/gazebo-plugin-subscribe-to-ros-topic/) by [Hanteus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2724/hanteus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-08-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-08-05**:
You probably need to use a single message description. Maybe this tutorial will help: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_i6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could not directly subscribe to ROS topics and use ROS messages by a transport node. You have 2 solutions to choose:

1. Declare a ROS node in your plugin and use it to subscribe to your ROS messages. And then fill your transport messages one field by one field.
2. Declare a transport node in your ROS node and publish your transport messages.

The second solution seems more convenient. I have not tried this way but I suggestion you tried it and told us whether it is feasible or not.

---

Originally posted by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) with karma: 449 on 2016-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hanteus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2724/hanteus/) on 2016-08-20**:
Thank you for your advice. I've choosen the first solution, since it's the one that also explained by this tutorial (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_i6).  Now I need to find a way to force the plugin to use my ros custom message.